# SpriteKit: unwanted stretching of sprite when resizing/scaling

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I've seen similar questions before but seems that no clear solution is provided. Currently I have a `SKScene` with child, contained by a `SKView`. Note: I'm not using a Game project; instead, I'm using the `SKView` in a normal `UIView`, and just add `SKView` as the subview of the `UIView`. The sprite itself is a small image, and it only occupies a certain portion in the middle-bottom part of the whole frame. The code looks something like this:

```
let imageView = SKView()
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: ..., y: ..., width: ..., height: ...) //all are predefined constants
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "image"))
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: imageView.frame.width * 0.5, y: imageView.frame.height * 0.5) // so it's positioned in the center
let scene = SKScene(size: imageView.frame.size) // also tried with sprite.size, but not working
scene.addChild(sprite)
scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
imageView.presentScene(scene)
self.frame.addSubview(imageView)
```

Now the problem is the sprite is not in its original shape; it's stretched along the vertical axis. I tried changing the `scaleMode` with all 5 choices: `.fill` / `.aspectFill` / `.aspectFit` / `.resizeFill` / `none`, but none of them give the sprite its original shape/ratio. I've also tried changing the constants for the `imageView`'s frame, but that only cuts the sprite (if `imageView.frame.height` is decreased). So may I know how to address this issue?

Comment: I've entered your code into a `GameViewController` `viewDidLoad` standard game template, and I'm not seeing any stretching with `.aspectFit`...

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine as written, so the problem is likely elsewhere. I modified it a little bit so you can test it out in a Playground. Just make a new Playground and copy and paste. You'll also have to drag in an image for your sprite.

```
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// create the outer UIView and show it on the playground
let outerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = outerView

// create the SKView and add it to the outer view
let imageView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 25, width: 250, height: 250))
outerView.addSubview(imageView)

// create the scene and present it
var scene = SKScene(size: imageView.frame.size)
imageView.presentScene(scene)

// create the sprite, position it, add it to the scene
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "worf.jpg"))
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: imageView.frame.width * 0.5, y: imageView.frame.height * 0.5)
scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
scene.addChild(sprite)
```

Here's the result:

[image]

No stretching! So your issue is probably related to the UIView you're placing it in. For example if you add:

```
outerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 2)
```

Now the image is stretched as you describe. Take a look at your containing view and everything above it.